# Django admin creating inline model object

Tags: django, django-admin, inline-formset, django-permissions, django-modeladmin

Inside my django admin, I am creating an admin model that has a one to many relationship with another table. Let us call it `Recipes` and `Ingredients`. Each recipe has multiple ingredients.

I want to make it so in the admin page a user can create a recipe and add certain ingredients to it on the same page. So I am using the concept of `inline models`. The issue is that once certain ingredients have been created only a few fields should be allowed to be edited. So I've created two separate inline models -- one for editing and one for adding.

The other issue is that ingredient creation can only be done if the user has certain permissions. If the user does not have those permissions it still creates the ingredients but they are not `published`. They later have to get approved by someone with the correct permissions. Right now I am overriding the `formset` for the creating of the ingredient. It looks like this:

```
class AddIngredientInlineFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    model = Ingredient

    def save(self, commit=True):
        can_publish = self.request.user.has_perm('meals.publish_ingredient')
        for form in self.forms:
            if form.cleaned_data:
                Ingredient.objects.create(
                     is_published = can_publish, **kwargs
                )

class AddIngredientInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Ingredient
    formset = AddIngredientInlineFormset
    fields = ['name', 'amount', 'description']
    extra = 1

    def has_change_permission(self, request):
        return False
```

Then I have a separate inline class for editing:

```
class EditIngredientInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Ingredient
    fields = ['name', 'amount', 'description']
    readonly_fields = ['name', 'amount']
    extra = 0
    can_delete = False

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False
```

Then in my recipe admin model, it looks like this:

```
class RecipeAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):

    model = models.Recipe
    list_display = ['name']

    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context={}):
        self.inlines = [AddIngredientInline]
        return super(BaseModelAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context={}):
        self.inlines = [EditIngredientInline, AddIngredientInline]
        return super(BaseModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

This works fine for adding recipes and ingredients for those recipes, and the display shows up fine for everything. However when I try to edit an existing ingredient for a given recipe I get the error: `IngredientFormFormSet' object has no attribute 'new_objects'`

I imagine this is happening because I am not using `formset.save()` for the `AddIngredientFormSet`. Also this has begun to get fairly complicated, so I am wondering if there is a better way to check the permissions for publishing the inline ingredient and save that column correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by doing this:

```
class AddIngredientInlineFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    model = Ingredient

    def save(self, commit=True):
        can_publish =    self.request.user.has_perm('meals.publish_ingredient')
        # use commit = false so it doesn't do a hard save since not all
        # the fields are present in the form.
        instances = super(AddIngredientInlineFormSet, self).save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            instance.random_variable = default_value
            instance.save()
```